# TextChange event of textbox is user initiated in wpf

Tags: wpf, textchanged

How can I determine the TextChange event of a textbox is initiated by a user?
TextChange event will be fired even when I change the text through code.
But I need to get the event only when user changes the text at GUI.

Answer (score 3):

Using a field you can check inside the `TextChanged` event handler in an encapsulated way:

```cs
internal void SetTextProgrammatically(string newValue)
{
    this.suppressTextChanged = true;
    try
    {
        // Set Text
        textBox.Text = newValue;
    }
    finally
    {
        this.suppressTextChanged = false;
    }
}
```

When you set the text through code use `SetTextProgrammatically`. In the `TextChangedHandler` just check the value of `suppressTextChanged`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `PreviewTextInput` event. This event will be called only when user inputs text in TextBox and not when you change Text in code behind

Comment: As far as I see, backspaces are also ignored... :(